# MYSQL - Concatenating two group concat functions into a list

Tags: mysql, group-by, concatenation, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

So i'm working with this data set based on a sneaker store, and what i need to do, is to get rid of duplicate fields containing shoe models that only differ in size.
What i'm trying to do, is to merge the columns that contain seperately the size and the amount on hand of that size (as in "US-9: 4 pairs, US-10: 11 pairs, US-7: 6 pairs etc.), and then merge the rows into a list with each size and it's corresponding quantity. This is the best i've been able to do so far

```
SELECT * FROM shoes;
+------------+------------+--------------+------+----------+
| primary_id | product_id | shoe         | size | quantity |
+------------+------------+--------------+------+----------+
|          1 |          1 | Nike Cortez  |   38 |        1 |
|          2 |          1 | Nike Cortez  |   41 |        4 |
|          3 |          2 | Adidas Samba |   38 |        5 |
|          4 |          2 | Adidas Samba |   39 |        3 |
|          5 |          3 | Puma Clyde   |   40 |        4 |
|          6 |          3 | Puma Clyde   |   41 |        2 |
+------------+------------+--------------+------+----------+

SELECT product_id, shoe, CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT size SEPARATOR ', '), " : ", GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quantity SEPARATOR ', ')) as `quantity_of_given_sizes` FROM shoes GROUP BY product_id;
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| product_id | shoe         | quantity_of_given_sizes |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|          1 | Nike Cortez  | 38, 41 : 1, 4           |
|          2 | Adidas Samba | 38, 39 : 3, 5           |
|          3 | Puma Clyde   | 40, 41 : 2, 4           |
+------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right.

First you need to concat the columns and then then the rows.

As you don't have a US column i omitted it

> ```
> SELECT 
>     product_id
>     , shoe
>     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( `size`,':' ,`quantity`) SEPARATOR  '|') as `quantity_of_given_sizes`
> FROM shoes 
> GROUP BY product_id, shoe;
> ```
>
> ```
> product_id | shoe         | quantity_of_given_sizes
> ---------: | :----------- | :----------------------
>          1 | Nike Cortez  | 38:1|41:4              
>          2 | Adidas Samba | 38:5|39:3              
>          3 | Puma Clyde   | 40:4|41:2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5a9551cceb99224d7061602d3398903b)*